# Cut edge between two parametric surfaces

Tags: surfaces, parametric

I want to make a model of an ultrasound field, that impinges on a test object. The shape of the sound field can be simplified as a cone and the test object is cylindric.
I used the following parametric equations:

Cone (with opening angle $\delta$):
$$
x=t*\cos(\phi_{cone});\;y=t*\sin(\phi_{cone});\;z=-\frac{t}{\tan(\delta)};
$$
$$
r_{cone,top} \le t \le r_{cone,bot}; \;\;
0 \le \phi_{cone} \le 2\pi
$$

Cylinder (with radius $a$):
$$
x=b;\;y=a*\cos(\phi_{cylinder});\;z=a*\sin(\phi_{cylinder});
$$
$$
-l_{cylinder}/2 \le b \le l_{cylinder}/2; \;\;
0 \le \phi_{cylinder} \le \pi
$$

To calculate the reflection and transmission, I thought of first finding the curve, where the two surfaces cut each other. Then I could calculate the angle between the sound field and the normal of the test objects surface. But I am somehow not able to find a parametric equation for the cut edge/curve. Is it even possible to solve this analytically? I added a picture to show, what it should look like.

[image]

Hope you can help me! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the cone $C$ be given by
$$(t,\phi)\mapsto {\bf c}(t,\phi):=(t\cos\phi,t\sin\phi, \mu t)\qquad(t\geq0, \ 0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi)\ .$$
For each fixed $\phi$ we get a generator $g_\phi$ of the cone with parametric representation
$$g_\phi:\quad t\mapsto (t\cos\phi,t\sin\phi, \mu t)\qquad(t\geq0)\ .$$
We now have to intersect $g_\phi$ with the cylinder $Z:\ y^2+z^2=a^2$. This amounts to solving
$$t^2(\sin^2\phi+\mu^2)=a^2$$
for $t$. It follows that $g_\phi$ intersects the cylinder $Z$ when $$t={a\over\sqrt{\sin^2\phi+\mu^2}}\ ,$$
that is to say in the point
$${\bf r}(\phi)={a\over\sqrt{\sin^2\phi+\mu^2}}(\cos\phi,\sin\phi,\mu)\qquad(0\leq\phi\leq2\pi)\ .\tag{1}$$
The  equation $(1)$ is a parametric representation of the curve $\gamma:=C\cap Z$.

In order to determine the angle under which $C$ and $S$ intersect at a point ${\bf r}(\phi)$ we have to compute the normals of $C$ and $S$ at this point. For $C$  this amounts to computing ${\bf c}_t\times {\bf c}_\phi$ (and normalizing), for $S$ to compute $\nabla f$ at ${\bf r}(\phi)$ for the function $f(x,y,z):=y^2+z^2-a^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great.